# How can I use render arrays to programmatically create a chart in a block?

Tags: 8, blocks, charts

I'm programming a block in Drupal 8:

```
class B extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
  public function build() {
    return []; // cannot figure out what to return here
  }
}
```

I read that in D8 a block's `build` function should return a render-array, like this:

```
return ['#markup' => 'Some HTML'];
```

Then in the Charts source code I found some examples here and there, especially in PHPDOC comments, so I built a render-array like this:

```
$return = [
  ‘chart’ => [
    '#type' => 'chart',
    '#chart_type' => 'line',
    '#chart_library' => 'c3',
    'xaxis' => [
                    '#type' => 'chart_xaxis',
                    '#title' => 'XTitle',
                    '#labels' => range(1, 10),
                ],
    'yaxis' => [
                    '#type' => 'chart_yaxis',
                    '#title' => 'YTitle'
                ],
    'series_1' => ['#type' => 'chart_data', '#title' => $seriesTitle,
                    '#data' => range(1, 10) ],
    // more series here keyed series_2, series_3 etc
  ]
];
```

Nothing is output (only block title).
No JS errors in console.
No error logs.
Example chart in demo module works, C3 is installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Versions:

- Drupal: 8.4.2
- Charts: charts-8.x-3.0-alpha6

Comment: `return ['chart' => []]`

Comment: Yes that’s what I was doing. Just mistyped it here in the question. Thanks for pointing out @Ivan

Comment: at place of placing blocks, if you want a separate route with all your graphs
https://www.drupal.org/project/charts/issues/2948433